# Json.NET XML conversion and TypeNameHandling.Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, json, json.net

### The immediate problem

Came across this problem when working with a different library that uses Json.NET. We've been making heavy use of `TypeNameHandling.Arrays` when serializing C# objects into JSON, as well as deserializing them on the other end of the wire in our client app.

However, it seems that Json.NET's `XmlNodeConverter` does not play nice with this setting, throwing errors when deserializing JSON such as:

```
{
  'people': {
    '$type': 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyNamespace.Person, MyDll]], mscorlib',
    '$values': [
      {
        'name': 'Alan'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Bob'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### The cause

Exception is thrown because Json.NET tries to interpret `$values` as a string attribute and not as child nodes. We get a null reference exception when `.ToString()` is called on a null value around XmlNodeConverter.cs:1367.

### Elaboration

The real issue here might stem in the way Json.NET handles arrays in XML: it does not produce a wrapper such as the one below:

```
<people json:type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyNamespace.Person, MyDll]], mscorlib">
  <person>
    <name>Alan</name>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Bob</name>
  </person>
</people>
```

...where it would be able to add the custom `json:type` attribute, but instead relies on implicitly grouping elements sharing the same tag:

```
<person>
  <name>Alan</name>
</item>
<person>
  <name>Bob</name>
</item>
```

This behaviour seems a little unintuitive to my untrained eye - I'd expect to have a parent element included in the XML rather than silently dropped. (This is likely also the reason why empty and one-element arrays need extra work as docuemented in many threads here and Json.NET forums.)

### Solutions..?

Here I turn to the community..!

1. Do you know of any workarounds, perhaps some setting that makes the two play nicely?
2. Is it the consensus that dropping the parent node is the right way to go about serializing arrays?

Comment: You could always write your own custom XmlNodeConverter to make it work how you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the impression you don't have much access to the way JSON.Net is being leveraged because you mention it is used by another library.  If you did have access you could consider options such as deserializing to an anonymous type then adding appropriate code to initialize your class.  (See: [Deserialize json with json.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378335/deserialize-json-with-json-net-c-sharp))

The JSON.net documentation mentions this:
http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm

> "Multiple nodes with the same name at the same level are grouped together into an array."
>
> "If the XML created from JSON doesn't match what you want then you will need to convert it
> manually. The best approach to do this is to load your JSON into a LINQ to JSON object
> like JObject or JArray and then use LINQ to create an XDocument. The opposite process,
> using LINQ with an XDocument to create a JObject or JArray, also works. Find out more
> about using LINQ to JSON with LINQ here."

To your specific questions:

1. There are no direct workarounds to make the deserialization work properly in JSON.net with arrays structured in that way if you can't edit the deserialization code.
2. Both methods are valid.  Json.NET tends to target writing JSON and XML that looks like something you might write by hand while .Net serializers are designed to ensure no data loss when deserializing again in .Net.  In general it is ideal to simply use the same library everywhere - in practice Json.NET is a popular choice.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer and attempting to directly answer my two questions!